# JQuery Hide not working for .after

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.match1').after('<div class="form-group">'+'</div>');
```

I am trying to hide it using

```
$('.match1').after().hide();
```

but its not working any suggestions

Comment: What about looking for the documentation of the function before asking a question ? A function doesn't do what you expect -> look at the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.next()` and not `.after()`. The `.after()` is for inserting and not selecting. Use the below code instead **to hide**:

```
$('.match1').next().hide();
```